# Error validating SAML message+Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation

Tags: spring-saml

I am new to ADFS, I m in a position to hit ADFS login screen where i m providing myself and all my colleagues credentials and it is validating perfect. After validation it is redirecting to spring-saml application with error "Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation". when i try to open other wildcard siter domains(*.csscrr.com) it is not asking authentication, so it concludes SSO is working perfect. Because of the Error page i can't move to next level. I m scratching my head to resolve the mentioned error.

Note : From my ADFS, 
i can see in federationmetadata xml as SignatureMethod Algorithm="#rsa-sha256"
and in my generated metadata i can see SignatureMethod Algorithm="rsa-sha1"